# Absolutely continuous functions with derivatives in Lp

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

It's a problem in Bass's real analysis book. suppose $p>1$ and $q$ is its conjugate exponent, $f$ is an absolutely continuous function on $[0,1]$ with $f' \in L^p$, and $f(0)=0$. prove that if $g \in L^q$, then $\int_{0}^{1}|fg|dx \leq (1/p)^{1/p} \parallel f' \parallel_p \parallel g \parallel_q$. I get the relationship between $f$ and $f'$ by property of AC,  $f(x)=f(0)+ \int_{1}^{x} f'(t)dt=\int_{0}^{x} f'(t)dt$,then by H$\ddot{o}$lder inequality, $\leq (\int_{0}^{x} |f'(t)|^{p}dt)^{1/p}*(\int_{0}^{x} 1^{q}dt)^{1/q} \leq (\int_{0}^{x} |f'(t)|^{p}dt)^{1/p}$. Then what can I do next? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is absolutely continuous with $f(0) = 0$, we can write

$$f(x) = \int_0^x f'(t)\, dt.$$

By Holder's inequality,

$$|f(x)| \le \left(\int_0^x 1^q \, dt\right)^{1/q} \left(\int_0^x |f'(t)|^p\, dt\right)^{1/p} = x^{1/q}\|f'\|_p.$$

Therefore

$$\|f\|_p = \|x^{1/q}\|_p \|f'\|_p = \left(\frac{1}{\frac{p}{q} + 1}\right)^{1/p} \|f'\|_p = \left(\frac{\frac{1}{p}}{\frac{1}{q} + \frac{1}{p}}\right)^{1/p}\|f'\|_p = \left(\frac{1}{p}\right)^{1/p}\|f'\|_p.$$

By Holder's inequality, we conclude

$$\|fg\|_1 \le \|f\|_p \|g\|_q = \left(\frac{1}{p}\right)^{1/p}\|f'\|_p \|g\|_q.$$

Comment: thanks, I made a mistake for estimation part